# Display order of data

Tags: mysql

I have an MySQL table that I would like sorted in a particular order when displayed on a Web page using PHP. In order to accomplish this I have a "displayorder" column with unique values. Rows with lower values in this column are displayed first.

The problem with this is that inserting new rows manually is difficult, because I have to adjust the "displayorder" for many many rows in order for the new row to fit. Is there a better way to do this that I don't know about?

The desired order may look like this:

```
Action
Adventure
MMO
Roleplaying
Simulation
Strategy
Software
Reference
```

Comment: How do you build the order in the first place? By date? Normally it is better to generate the order in the select query on-the-fly.

Comment: A lot of them are alphabetical, but there are also rows I need to list at the bottom of the table. It's very arbitrary.

Comment: Then put that logic in the `order by` of your `select` query. No need for a column to store it

Comment: Add more steps between records for example the first row's order column hold 100 means the next one holds 200. If you like to insert new one in-between these two add a sort value 150. In google, search for weighted sort logics.

Comment: I updated my question with an example of desired output.

Comment: @juergen d:  I don't see how I can do this using `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a procedure that will perform the insert and the shifting of order and use it instead of writting `INSERT INTO ...` in php

In example :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  orderPlace INT NOT NULL,
  datas VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'foo'
);

INSERT INTO test (orderPlace) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertNewRowAndShiftOrder;

DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewRowAndShiftOrder(IN OrderValue INT,
                                           IN SomeData VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT, OrderValue, SomeData);

    SET @LastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    UPDATE test SET orderPlace = orderPlace + 1
    WHERE orderPlace >= OrderValue
    AND id <> @LastId;
END$

DELIMITER ;

CALL InsertNewRowAndShiftOrder(5, 'bar');

SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY orderPlace;
```

This outputs :

```
id  orderPlace datas    
1   1          foo  
2   2          foo  
3   3          foo  
4   4          foo  
11  5          bar  
5   6          foo  
6   7          foo  
7   8          foo  
8   9          foo  
9   10         foo  
10  11         foo
```

---

Note : I can't provide a DB-fiddle link, because this doesn't work, for some reasons on that website. I tested on my localhost MySQL DB and it worked

Answer (score 2):

One fairly simple way to do this is to create the sort column as [`decimal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) rather than an [integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). This way, you start your table with values such as `1`, `2`, `3` etc', and when you want to insert a record between `1` and `2` you simply insert it as `1.5`.

For a table that updates frequently, you want to choose a large number of decimal digits (the maximum, `decimal(65,30)` would probably be too big for this, but it's a possible choice).